# Help with proving that vectors are conjugate.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've been looking through a few of my lecture notes on optimization, and there was a thing that confused me about the conjugate gradient methods.

In the following definition we assume that the $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is positive definite.

Definition: Nonzero vectors $d_i \in \mathbb{R^n}$, $i=0,1,...,m$ are called conjugate if $d_i^TAd_j=0$, $\forall\text{ } i\neq j$.

Properties:

1. $d_i^TAd_i>0$;
2. Conjugate directions $d_0,...,d_m$ are linearly independent;
3. If $d_0,d_1,...,d_{n-1}$ is a complete set of eigenvectors of $A$, then they are conjugate. (Exercise: prove it)

What I don't really understand is how to prove property 3. Let's say we have a complete set of eigenvectors, and let's say we take two linearly independent of these eigenvectors, $d_1$ and $d_2$, corresponding to eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, respectively. Let's assume that $\lambda_2 \neq 0$. Then we get:
$$d_1^TAd_2=d_1^T \cdot (\lambda_ 2d_2)= \lambda_2(d_1^Td_2)$$

Now we should get that $d_1^Td_2=0$ if they're conjugate, according to the definition. This should mean that they are orthogonal though, if I'm not mistaken. How can I be certain that they are? The matrix is just positive definite, and there is no mention of it being Hermitian or anything like that, so how should I be able to prove that there exists an ON-basis for $A$ consisting of eigenvectors, which I suppose is the only way to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two eigenvectors belonging to two different eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are always orthogonal. This is because

$$\lambda_1 v_1^T v_2 = (\lambda_1 v_1)^T v_2 = (Av_1)^T v_2 = v_1^T A^T v_2 = v_1^T A v_2 = v_1^T (Av_2) = v_1^T(\lambda_2 v_2) = \lambda_2 v_1^T v_2$$

Thus, you have an equality $\lambda_1 x = \lambda_2 x$ which is only possible if either $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$  or $x=0$.

Comment: Ok. But how do I know that the matrix is symmetric in the first place? Is this just common knowledge for a positive definite matrix with a basis of eigenvectors?

Comment: @Scounged It depends a little bit what you mean by positive definite. Usually symmetry is built into the definition of positive definite. However, there are matrices which are not symmetric but are "positive definite" in the sense that $x^T A x>0$ for every nonzero $x$. These matrices needn't have any of the other good properties of what we usually call positive definite matrices, such as having positive eigenvalues. (In fact they needn't even have *real* eigenvalues.) As a consequence people sometimes say "symmetric positive definite" to be absolutely clear what is meant.

Comment: @Scounged To be less roundabout: in the context of conjugate gradient, "positive definite" means "symmetric positive definite". (It might be the case that positive definite in the sense that $x^T A x>0$+diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$ implies symmetric, though. That's an interesting question...)

Comment: @Scounged Usually, positive definite is only defined for symmetric matrices.

Comment: Ok, I had no idea about that. I guess I've not been paying enough attention in class then. I just assumed that positive definite meant that all the eigenvalues were positive.

Comment: @Scounged In a certain sense it does, but some generalization is required. In general, positive definiteness is relative to some inner product. A matrix $A$ is positive definite with respect to the inner product $(x,y)$ if it is self-adjoint with respect to this inner product and $(x,Ax)>0$ if $x$ is nonzero. Out of context, we assume that this is the Euclidean inner product, for which being self-adjoint means being symmetric.

Comment: @Scounged On the other hand, if a nonsymmetric, diagonalizable matrix $A$ has positive eigenvalues, then there exists a *different* inner product with respect to which $A$ is positive definite. This inner product can be defined by taking a basis consisting of eigenvectors of $A$ and choosing them to be orthonormal to one another. Then bilinearity extends this definition to the whole space.

Comment: @Ian I think you answered OPs question *and then some*! Awesome explanation, I feel like you should get the rep. from this question, not me!